# Allocation free game

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

My code is basically allocation free, however the GC runs every 30 seconds or so when at 60fps. Checking the app with DDMS for allocation shows there is ALOT of `SimpleListIterator` being allocated. There is also some stuff being allocated because i use [`Exchanger`](http://d.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html).

The SimpleListIterator comes from for each loops `for (T obj : objs) {}`. I was under the impression that the compilator/translator would optimize those to not use iterators for types that support it (I basically only use ArrayList) but that seems to not be the case.

How can I avoid allocating all these `SimpleListIterators`? One solution would be to switch to regular for loops `for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {}` but I like for each loops :(

Another way would be to extend ArrayList which returns an `Iterator` that is only allocated once.

A third way I hacked together is using a static helper function which returns a `Collection` which is reusing an `Iterator`. I hacked something like this together but the casting feels very hackish and unsafe. It should be thread safe though as I use `ThreadLocal`? See below:

```
public class FastIterator {
    private static ThreadLocal<Holder> holders = new ThreadLocal<Holder>();

    public static <T> Iterable<T> get(ArrayList<T> list) {
        Holder cont = holders.get();

        if (cont == null) {
            cont = new Holder();

            cont.collection = new DummyCollection<T>();
            cont.it = new Iterator<T>();

            holders.set(cont);
        }

        Iterator<T> it = (Iterator<T>) cont.it;
        DummyCollection<T> collection = (DummyCollection<T>) cont.collection;

        it.setList(list);
        collection.setIterator(it);

        return collection;
    }

    private FastIterator() {}

    private static class Holder {
        public DummyCollection<?> collection;
        public Iterator<?> it;
    }

    private static class DummyCollection<T> implements Iterable {
        private Iterator<?> it;

        @Override
        public java.util.Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return (java.util.Iterator<T>) it;
        }

        public void setIterator(Iterator<?> it) {
            this.it = it;
        }
    }

    private static class Iterator<T> implements java.util.Iterator<T> {
        private ArrayList<T> list;
        private int size;
        private int i;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return i < size;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            return list.get(i++);
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {

        }

        public void setList(ArrayList<T> list) {
            this.list = list;
            size = list.size();
            i = 0;
        }

        private Iterator() {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, so if I understand you correctly, hacking iterators is better than the one extra line needed to get the value in a `for` loop?...

Comment: Point taken. Guess I should just bite together and ditch for each loops? :(

Comment: I've used the "extend ArrayList which returns an Iterator that is only allocated once" version.  One thing to watch out for (with all the iteration styles you mention) is nested iteration.  In my version I added an explicit "release" method and could sanity check that the iterator was not already in use... caught a nasty bug that way.  Another note: it is legal to have Iterator.remove throw an UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: Is this actually affecting performance, or are you just annoyed that a program you thought wasn't allocating anything turns out to be?

Comment: The GC runs every 30e second, pausing the game for about 100ms causing noticeable stutter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use for each in Android games.
I think this [official video](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/writing-real-time-games-android.html) talks about that too.

Comment: I decided to just covert all loops to regular for loops. KISS.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best approach would be to use a Decorator design.  Create a class which takes a collection in the constructor and implements the Iterable interface by calling the wrapped class and reusing the iterator returned.

Comment: I believe the heart of this suggestion is to also have a reset() method that returns the iterator to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Two additional approaches for avoiding the allocation of iterators. 
First is to use a callback idiom:

```
public interface Handler<T> {
  void handle(T element);
}

public interface Handleable<T> {
  void handleAll(Handler<T> handler);
}

public class HandleableList<T> extends ArrayList<T> implements Handleable<T> {
  public void handleAll(Handler<T> handler) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); ++i) {
      handler.handle(get(i));
    }
  }
}
```

This approach still requires an instance of a Handler to receive the callback, but this can definitely reduce allocations when, for example, you are trying to visit the elements of several lists.

Second approach is to use a cursor idiom:

```
public interface Cursor<T> {
  void reset();
  boolean next();
  T current();
}

public class CursoredList<T> extends ArrayList<T> implements Cursor<T> {
  private int _index = -1;

  public void reset() {
    _index = -1;
  }

  public boolean next() {
    return ++_index >= size();
  }

  public T current() {
    return get(_index);
  }
}
```

Sure, this is the same as implementing Iterable and Iterator on your subtype of ArrayList, but this clearly shows the cursor location as state on the collection itself.